# sum of all columns in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

sum of all columns in sql

i have 48 columns with 40,000 rows.

I want a new row which is sum of all columns.

I know I can do:

```
select sum(a), sum(b), sum(c) .....but i have to type that 48 times.
```

Is there a better way ?

the column has `int` values. And also has a lot of 0's

Comment: Sounds like you have a de-normalized data structure -- a repeating block of 48 columns should probably be 48 rows in some other table.  Gosh, if it were structured like that, you wouldn't have to type `sum()` 48 times.

Comment: I don't know about sql-server-2008, but many SQL servers carry around their table schemata in a table themselves, so maybe you could do a `select` on that table to get your 48 column names.

Comment: Dynamic SQL is the way to go. But seriously, I think your schema has a problem.

Answer (score 2):

This problem smacks of poor design, you should fix your structure, most likely each of your 48 column names could be a value in a single column next to the column you're aggregating (or another table altogether).

Then you'd have a simple query like below that returns 48 rows:

```
SELECT col1,SUM(col2)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY col1
```

Fixing the structure is ideal, but you can get what you're after using system views:

```
SELECT ',SUM('+c.name+')'
FROM  sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c
  ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'YourTable'
```

You could make it dynamic so you can execute it all at once, but if you're just looking for a quick way to save some keystrokes that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not forced to use `sum` 48 times.

You can retrieve all the column names querying the `information_schema`. Then loop over all these columns and execute the query.

This query would return the column_names of your table :

```
select column_name
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'yourTable'
and table_schema = 'yourSchema'
```

Then you just need to loop over each column_name and execute the query as a `string` using [`sp_executesql`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Simply set the column name in the string the value of the current iteration in the loop.

If you want all the `columns` returned in one time, you can use `union`.

I think you have all what is needed here to accomplish what you want.