Select rows with at least one non-zero value
I have a table with 20+ columns and some rows would only have 0s for all the column. Is there a way to filter out rows where all the columns have 0?
I could use
select * 
from table 
where concat(col1, col2, col3) != '000'

but I don't want to write 20+ zeroes in my case and there is a possibility that the column count could increase in the future.
I could also use
select * 
from table 
where coalesce(col1, col2, col3) > 0 
   or coalesce(col1, col2, col3) < 0 

as some values could be negative. But I don't want to write 20+ column names.
Is there a dynamic way to solve this issue?

"I don't want to write 20+ zeroes in my case and there is a possibility that the column count could increase in the future." sounds like, therefore, the problem is your design, and your data is denormalised.

Redesign your schema.

"But I don't want to write 20+ column names." That's what you need to do with your current design. That you "don't want to" doesn't make that not the solution.

Which version are you using? In SQL Server 2022 or Azure SQL you can use LEAST. In all other versions you have to write the conditions. If you want to take advantage of indexing you can't use COALESCE

you can use openjson trick to dynamically unvpiot a row and then do what you need. it needs some special care for nulls and floats, but it's not impossible. Are you implementing chess bitboards in tsql or what's with all the columns?

'000' isn't 0 either. It's a 3-character string. GREATEST won't work here, unless you're absolutely sure there will never be any strings ordered before 0, eg # or (

Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58928964/how-to-check-all-the-columns-are-0-in-sql-server-without-specifying-all-columns

see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443401/sum-of-all-columns-in-sql

Could you show us some sample data and expected outcome please

What datatype have those columns?

Please read : Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

'there is a possibility that the column count could increase in the future.' - then you have to go with dynamic sql if you don't want to have the query produce unexpected results when new columns are added but you haven't been told, and I don't see how you know which columns should be tested unless you have some sort of identifier eg naming convention. ie its a bad design

Please try the following solution leveraging SQL Server's Quantified Expressions (XQuery) functionality.
It will work starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards.
It is completely dynamic regardless of how many columns are in the table.
And no need in any dynamic SQL.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT, col4 INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES
(0, 0, 0, 0),
(0, -18, 0, 0),
(0, 0, 0, 0);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT *
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT x.value('every $r in /root/*[local-name()!="id"]/text()
         satisfies $r = "0"', 'BIT')) AS t2(result)
WHERE t2.result = 0;

Output



id
col1
col2
col3
col4
result




2
0
-18
0
0
0




Use Dynamic SQL constructed from sys.tables and sys.colums info. Sum the columns using ABS then compare to zero.
If using SQL SERVER older than 2017:
DECLARE @Criteria Varchar(max) =''
DECLARE @SQL NVarchar(max) =''

SELECT @Criteria=STUFF
( 
  (SELECT '+' + 'ABS('+ QUOTENAME(c.name) +')'
   FROM  sys.tables t
   JOIN sys.columns c  ON t.object_id = c.object_id
   WHERE t.name = 'Example'
   FOR XML PATH ('')
  ), 1, 1, ''
)  
    
--SELECT @Criteria returns ABS([A])+ABS([B])+ABS([C])

SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM Example WHERE ' +  @Criteria + ' !=0'

--SELECT @SQL Returns SELECT * FROM Example WHERE ABS([A])+ABS([B])+ABS([C]) !=0
 
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

If SQL Server 2017+:
DECLARE @Criteria Varchar(max) =''
DECLARE @SQL NVarchar(max) =''

SELECT @Criteria=STRING_AGG('ABS('+ QUOTENAME(c.name) +')','+')
FROM  sys.tables t
JOIN sys.columns c
  ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'Example'
  
SET @SQL='SELECT * FROM Example WHERE ' +  @Criteria + ' !=0'
    
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

fiddle

No need to use the old hat string concat trick, STRING_AGG is almost mainstream now!

STRING_AGG was only added in  SQL Server 2017 (14.x)

Only, 2017 is already out of mainstream support! For older versions, you should use for xml trick, the string concat is only applicable for i dunno, sql server 2000, and it's not guaranteed to work even there

You should really be using QUOTENAME here for safe(r) injection of columns name, and shouldn't be using EXEC(@SQL) syntax; use sys.sp_executesql. Then if the OP needs to parametrise the query they can. I've all too often seen people start off with EXEC(@SQL) syntax and then end up with a (nasty) SQL Injection vulnerability when they "parametrise" the statement by injecting their parameters.

But, @siggemannen, is right, you should not be using the method you have in the first query. SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM is a documented antipattern and should be avoided.

@Thom A what is the recommended pattern prior to 2017?

The FOR XML PATH  (and STUFF) method, @BartMcEndree . I describe it at length in my answer to String_agg for SQL Server before 2017.

@Thom Pre 2017 query corrected to use STUFF and FOR XML. fiddle updated.

I agree it's very misleading and a bad idea to write answers with obsolete functions unless OP explicitely requests it because they also use obsolete versions. People who have similar issues will read the answer and copy a really bad query instead of using far better options.

JSON method (FOR JSON)can process a table row as a collection. After that, you can dissect the assembly and check that the conditions are met.
See example.
Test source data
create table test (id int,col1 int,col2 int,col3 int);
insert into test values
 (1,10,11,12)
,(2,20,21,22)
,(3,0,0,0)
,(4,30,0,33)
;




id
col1
col2
col3




1
10
11
12


2
20
21
22


3
0
0
0


4
30
0
33



Target query. We do not use column names in query, except id column.
select *
  ,case when replace(replace(
    json_modify( 
        (SELECT * FROM test t2 where t2.id=t.id FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER )
            ,'$.id',null)
      ,'":0,"','":null,"'),'":0}','":null}') like '%:[0-9]%' 
   then 1 
   else 0 end fl
from test t
;

And output



id
col1
col2
col3
fl




1
10
11
12
1


2
20
21
22
1


3
0
0
0
0


4
30
0
33
1



Same query step by step
select *
  ,case when jv3 like '%:[0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end fl
from(
  select *
    ,replace(replace(jv2,'":0,"','":null,"'),'":0}','":null}') jv3
  from(
    select *
     ,json_modify(jv,'$.id',null)jv2
    from(
       select id
         ,(SELECT * FROM test t2 where t2.id=t.id 
           FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER ) jv
       from test t
     )a
   )b
)c;




id
jv
jv2
jv3
fl




1
{"id":1,"col1":10,"col2":11,"col3":12}
{"col1":10,"col2":11,"col3":12}
{"col1":10,"col2":11,"col3":12}
1


2
{"id":2,"col1":20,"col2":21,"col3":22}
{"col1":20,"col2":21,"col3":22}
{"col1":20,"col2":21,"col3":22}
1


3
{"id":3,"col1":0,"col2":0,"col3":0}
{"col1":0,"col2":0,"col3":0}
{"col1":null,"col2":null,"col3":null}
0


4
{"id":4,"col1":30,"col2":0,"col3":33}
{"col1":30,"col2":0,"col3":33}
{"col1":30,"col2":null,"col3":33}
1



fiddle

You can dynamically grab the columns on your table using the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "your_database" 
  AND TABLE_NAME = "your_table"


This is definitely going to error; most likely with the errors "Invalid column name 'your_database'." and "Invalid column name 'your_table'." Not to mention this answer makes no attempt to then demonstrate how the resultset returned would be used.

Not the mention, as well, why "your database" for the TABLE_SCHEMA? TABLE_SCHEMA doesn't contain the database name. Why not use the sys objects?

Seems like this is the outcome from ChatGPT or a similar tool and the input question was not asked very clever.

This is definitely going to error; most likely with the errors "Invalid column name 'your_database'." and "Invalid column name 'your_table'." Not to mention this answer makes no attempt to then demonstrate how the resultset returned would be used.
